# format datetime to shortdatestring in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my model, i have;

```
public class ReportDetails 
{
    public DateTime? MailSent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller;

```
var query = (from u in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.LennoxSurveyResponses
                             join c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.MailingListEntries on u.SurveyCode equals c.SurveyCode
                             join cl in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.MailingLists on c.MailingListId equals cl.MailingListId
                             join ch in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.Channels on cl.ChannelId equals ch.ChannelId
                             join cg in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups on ch.ChannelGroupId equals cg.ChannelGroupId
                             where ch.OrganizationId == 8
                             && ch.ChannelId == model.ChannelId
                             select new ReportDetails
                             {
                                 MailSent = c.LetterDate,
                                 DateCompleted = c.EmailDate
                             });
            model.Report = query.ToList();
```

Now in my view, I have

```
@foreach (var tr in Model.Report)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@tr.MailSent
                        </td>
                        <td>@tr.DateCompleted
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

When the results are displayed, the `MailSent` and `DateCompleted` have both date and time. I am trying to just display the Date without the Time. If I try `@tr.MailSent.HasValue ? @tr.MailSent.Value.ToShortDateString() : @tr.MailSent;` then i get an error - `Value cannot be null`. How would i display just the date part. Both `MailSent` and `DateCompleted` are nullable fields. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

#### an extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ShortDate(this DateTime? dateTime)
{
    if (dateTime.hasValue)
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(dateTime.ToShortDateString());
    else
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("Your other option");
}

View usage:
<td>@tr.MailSent.ShortDate()</td>
```

#### or inline:

```
@(tr.MailSent.HasValue ? @tr.MailSent.Value.ToShortDateString() : DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

#### or a default value

```
@tr.MailSent.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: i get an error on the view: there is not an implicit conversion between string and system.datetime? when i try your inline option. I will check with the first one.

Comment: @bladerunner no you'll need to replace the "has no value" option with a valid datetime. I've updated my example, but the last option is probably the easiest route

Comment: Cool, this works, @(tr.MailSent.HasValue ? @tr.MailSent.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty)..Thanks!!

Comment: @bladerunner if it helped, hit the up arrow on the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in code rather than the view:

```
select new ReportDetails
{
    MailSent = c.LetterDate.HasValue ? c.LetterDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
    DateCompleted = c.EmailDate.HasValue ? c.EmailDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about blowing up Razor

```
<tr>
    <td>@tr.MailSent</td>
    <td>@tr.DateCompleted</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When i try that, i get Nullable object must have a value exception.

Comment: I tried that too..Both MailSent and DateCompleted are nullable Datetime in my model. In order to try your fix, i would have to declare them as string in my model. When i do that, i get an error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: make sure you're no longer `ToShortDateString()`ing your viewmodel properties if you change your Model properties to `string`